# Correct way to say "I am a beginner in Japanese"

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-で

What is the correct way to say: "I am a beginner in Japanese".

Google Translate shows the translation is:

> 私は日本語**で**初心者です

However, Google search shows:

> 私は日本語**の**初心者です

has a lot more hits.

Which one of these is correct?

Comment: Do you know any Japanese, or are you just second-guessing from the search results? Do you know the difference between で and の?

Comment: I am learning Japanese. I roughly understand difference between で and の, but not exactly clear in this context. I understand で is used when referring language, e.g. Thank youは　日本語で　何ですか。However, in this context, 日本語 looks like an adjective to 初心者, so I am not entirely sure. Please let me know the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to say it is:

> 私は日本語の初心者です。
>
> I'm a beginner of Japanese language.

However, if you use the other variant, you'll still be understood, of course. After all, you are a beginner. :)

Still, it's kind of difficult to say this. Why not say something simple, like:

> 私【わたし】は日本語【にほんご】を勉強【べんきょう】します。まだ上手【じょうず】じゃありません。
>
> I study Japanese. I'm not skilled yet.

You'll likely be saying the first thing in any case, and the second part is what you're looking for.

Edit: as pointed out by [Shizuma_Hanazono](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/7207/shizuma-hanazono), it's better still to say:

> 私【わたし】は日本語【にほんご】を勉強【べんきょう】**しています**。

This means you are currently studying Japanese. The 〜ている form (progressive tense) is used to indicate ongoing actions. The earlier sentence I gave you is simplified, and if you're a beginner you're probably only familiar with the 〜ます form.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I think your suggestion is good and is more clear.

Comment: 勉強しています instead of 勉強します is better. The construction ~ている states that you are currently studying Japanese, and ~ている should generally be used to express ongoing actions.

Comment: I agree @Shizuma_Hanazono, that would be better. I assumed the poster is not familiar with the 〜ている construction yet, so that's why I went with the simpler one. But it's best to add this in as well, so I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thanks all. Indeed, I don't know the usage of ている before. Thanks for letting me know this.